# SvelteKit using miniflare with `modules: true`

Tags: vite, sveltekit, cloudflare-workers

Based on the example in this GitHub comment, https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/issues/2966#issuecomment-1251898659, I am trying to use Cloudflare workers locally by passing a miniflare instance to `platform.env` when in development. My issue is I need to load worker functions which are exported with module syntax and that requires `modules: true` enabled in the miniflare API (https://miniflare.dev/core/modules/#enabling-modules). This, in-turn, requires `--experimental-vm-modules` to be set in NodeJS.

However, since I am using `SvelteKit` I cannot seem to access this? Running `vite dev -- --experimental-vm-modules` does not work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am expecting to be able to use a miniflare configuration like this with SvelteKit:

```
const miniflare = new Miniflare({
    modules: true,
    scriptPath: '../functions/dist/workers.js'
})
```